# CSS: Expand height of column in a fixed size overflow div

Tags: html, css

I want to expand the height of a column in a fixed size overflowed div.

With the `overflow: auto`, `height: 100%` doesn't expand to the end of the scroll.

In my JSFiddle, I want the red column to be the same size as the blue.

https://jsfiddle.net/4g0v66sL/

Comment: This sounds like a job for [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blazemonger said, you can achieve this using `display: flex` on a div inside your overflowed div.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="row row-scroll">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="column blue">
          AAA BB CC DD AAA BB CC DD AAA BB CC DD D AAA BB CC DD AAA BB CC DD
        </div>
        <div class="column red">
          BBB
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-scroll {
  height: 130px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

See the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecw7zkmL/)

Comment: i tried the same but i didn't work .. i forget to remove the 100% from height :p so i went for a *hacky* solution

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that I had to remove height 100% from one of the columns ;)